# Can a maven wagon be a plugin simultaneously

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-wagon-plugin

Is it possible for a maven wagon jar to also be a plugin. To achieve this requires to set the packaging to maven-plugin.
Is this going to cause any repercussions with regards to the wagon?

Comment: Can you explain more in detail what you like to achieve ?

Comment: I have developed a maven wagon. I want to add some maven mojos to my wagon project. Wagons are in the form of jars. In order to make this plugin operating as a plugin I need to change the packaging to maven-plugin. Thus are there gonna be any repercussions on the wagon usage due to changing the packaging?

Comment: Can you please add an example project to show what you are doing? What kind of Wagon have you developed? For what purpose?

Comment: Edited the original question. Added the wagon project on the feature branch that also implements the plugin functionality.
The wagon uploads artefacts to s3. I also added  plugin functionality to upload/download files to s3 (thus the need for a plugin).

Comment: You know that many of them already exist for example: https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven ?

Comment: Yes I know. The project I implemented gives support on google, aws and azure and also gives some extra configuration options.

Comment: In any case, is having a plugin that is simultaneously a wagon a bad practise according to the maven standards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a technical perspective a maven wagon can be a maven plugin simultaneously and it shall operate as expected wether used as a wagon or a plugin.